# How to move image in ToolBar in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, toolbar

I was wondering if anyone knew how to move an image in a toolbar slightly to the right within the toolbar so its not so close to the edge of the pane.

This is currently what I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZnzX.png

I want it to be moved only by a couple pixels to the right so its more central in the toolbar.

Im currently using an imageview which is assigned to a label to display the image in a toolbar

Thank you for any help

this is the code I have:

```
Image robotIcon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("robot-16.png"));
ImageView robotView = new ImageView(robotIcon);
robotView.setFitHeight(50);
robotView.setFitWidth(50);

Label robotImage = new Label("");
    robotImage.setGraphic(robotView);



ToolBar toolBar2 = new ToolBar();
    toolBar2.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    toolBar2.getItems().addAll(
            controlLabel,
            new Separator(),
            gameLabel,
            rdoStart,
            rdoStop,
            new Separator(),
            animationLabel,
            rdoRestart,
            new Separator(),
            simulationLabel,
            btnRobot,
            delRobot,
            new Separator(),
            robotLabel,
            difSizeRobot,
            sameSizeRobot,
            new Separator(),
            robotSpeedLabel,
            difSpeedRobot,
            sameSpeedRobot,
            new Separator(),
            objectSpawnLabel,
            solidObject,
            solidCircle,
            robotImage
        );
```

Comment: If you just want to move it by a fixed number of pixels, you can simply do `robotImage.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5))` (for example). If you actually want to center it, try setting the max width of the label to `Double.MAX_VALUE` and setting the `alignment` to `CENTER` (though I am not entirely certain how a toolbar manages its layout).

Comment: @James_D ohhh didn't think about the setPadding thing, but that has solved the problem! I can now move it in the toolbar, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to add some padding to the label:

```
robotImage.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5));
```